# Subversion: find last logfile entries over entire repo?

Tags: svn

I've been away for a few months and I'm trying to find out what a contractor has been doing on a project.

My old trunk checkout is up to date, but `svn status -u` shows that there are later versions. If I run `find` on the repo, I can see that various revprop files have been changed over the last few months, and they have new version numbers, so something has been going on. The last trunk version was, for the sake of argument, 1000, and the status and find commands show that there are new revs up to 1100. `svn log -r` shows nothing for any version above 1000.

There are about a dozen branches that he could have been working on, but `svn ls` and `svn cat` on the branch files are not showing anything obvious. So, how do I get a log file for the new revisions, without having to check out every branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `svn log` on the working copy, you will only get entries relevant to the current subtree you are working on. As you need to look across "every branch", you should perform the query on the top of the repository tree.

Many `svn` commands allow you to perform the operation directly on the repository (rather than the working copy) by specifying its URL. The symbol `^` is a shortcut for this URL.

So, to view every log entry from `1000` onwards, across every branch, use:

```
svn log -r 1000:HEAD ^/
```